# my redis client can only get the confirmation of initial channel connection but not the message

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I am testing the Redis Pub/Sub in Python-3. I have a python script (client A) publish a message to a channel. I have another python script (client B) to subscribe the channel and retrieve the message. The two scripts are in two different python files. However, B can not get the message, but only the confirmation of connected channel.

```
a = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
a.publish('flag','good job')
```

#

```
b = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
p = b.pubsub()
p. subscribe(['flag'])

while True:
    for m in p.listen():
        if m['type'] == 'subscribe':
            print('channel connected')
        elif m['type'] == 'message':
            print (m['data'])
        else:
            print('something wrong!')
```

The outputs from my terminal:
channel connected

What i am expecting are: the full message contents following after the "channel connected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you must using `p.get_message()` instead of `p.listen()`?

Read this https://medium.com/@johngrant/python-redis-pub-sub-6e26b483b3f7

Comment: thank you! where i can find all the APIs related with pub/sub and their explanations?

Comment: 1. [https://redis.io/topics/pubsub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub); 2. [https://redis.io/commands/pubsub](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub); 3. [search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=I2kAXeTDGq6EmwXs0bDQCw&q=python+redis+pub+sub&oq=python+redis+pub+sub&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.0.0..59802...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.am2A6zTATjU)